# Can I use a 3 pin kettle power lead instead of a 2 pin kettle power lead

Tags: power

I have a computer appliance that only accepts a 2-pin kettle power cord (UK plug type). I don't have a 2-pin available at the moment; only a 3-pin. The third pin that is missing is the ground connection. Would it be ok for me to use the 3-pin kettle? Both are 10 Amp, 240 V cables.

[image: 2-pin][image: 3-pin]

Comment: what a kettle is supposed to do in this scenario?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič in some areas, these are called Kettle Leads (UK) or Jug Cords (NZ/AU) because they were used on benchtop water-heating jugs in kitchens back before "cordless" bases were common.

Comment: @Criggie Thanks for the explanation. I couldn't understood where a ketttle with only two wires are produced. In fact the question is not related to the kettle, rather just a mains plug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are [IEC 60320](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320) standard appliance cables.  This standard includes many different shapes for the connecting plugs and sockets, and they have been carefully designed so that unsafe combinations are physically impossible.  It *is* safe to use this "C13" cable (10 amps, grounded, three wires) to power a device with a "C18" socket (10 amps, ungrounded, two pins), and therefore the connector shapes allow you to do so.

(Ironically, one of those impossible combinations is using a C13 cable to power an actual electric kettle; that's considered a high-temperature application and it requires a C15 cable.  But you can use a C15 cable on a device designed for C13.)

Comment: *Certain* unsafe combinations are physically impossible.  No attempt is made to guard against connecting a 220-250V lead into a device which can only safely handle 110V-125V.

Answer (score 7):

If your device only has two connectors, it seems to be insulated. Then you don't need a ground connection. If the cable with the three connectors fits into the socket of the 2 pin, I don't see a problem.

Comment: Thank you, works fine.